# How to reply with only selected text using Mutt?

Tags: email, neovim, mutt, gnus

In the emacs mail program Gnus it is possible to:

> ‘R’
>
> Send a reply to the current article and yank the current article
> (‘gnus-article-reply-with-original’).  If the region is active, only
> yank the text in the region.

The part I am interested in replicating is yanking only the text in the active region. Is this possible in Mutt when using vim/nvim as the editor? That is, when viewing the message can one select/highlight text and then invoke 'r' to have the reply contain only this region?